# When can a sequence $x_n$ be treated as a point?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

The following is a proof for the Intermediate Value Theorem form Terence Tao's Analysis I. What I'm wondering is why can we call the sequence $x_n$ a "point" from the start; since the sequence $x_n$ is used to prove the existence of the limit point $c$ it makes sense but why is it valid? Is it fair to call it a point because it converges? I think he might've called it a "point" because that's a statement we use often with the supremum and that would be familiar to the reader but I'm not sure if it's the clearest way to state it. So, is it rigorous? And if so, why?

[image]

Comment: $x_n$ is not the entire sequence, but just one element in that sequence. You seem to have a one-dimensional space, where every number can be seen as a point in that space.

Comment: But isn't it subsequently treated as a sequence? I don't understand how both can be true.

Comment: The point $x_n$ depends on $n$, so you have a suitable $x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots$ and thus a sequence of $x_n$s.  From the construction, they cannot all be the same point.  If they were all some $z < \sup(E)$ then it would not work for $n>\frac1{\sup(C)-z)}$

Comment: Can you find a place where $x_n$ is _defined as a sequence_?

Comment: There isn't one, it was an assumption based on the notation and the fact that it converges. The comments comments sort of cleared things up. It's the first I'm seeing something like this so encountering more instances where this is being used should make things even clearer. I just hope I do encounter it.